# unable to get .asc file from gpg command

Tags: java, gnupg

We are trying to generate a gpg encrypted file (in .asc format) from java. When executed from command prompt , .asc with encrypted string is created in the path given but when run from Java the file is not getting created.

Code --

```
         try {

            command = "gpg -aer user --yes  <path>/<filename>";

            System.out.println("gpg cmmd - -----------"+command);

            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();

            Process p1 = rt.exec(command);

            p1.waitFor();
            int exitCode = p1.exitValue();
            System.out.println("exit - "+exitCode);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            ie.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            //TODO
        }
```

Expectation is that the .asc file should get created in the same path as that of the source file. But unable to see the same getting generated.

Can anyone please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're missing a whole set of crucial information. What's the exit code? What's printed on STDOUT/STDERR? What's the _exact_ GnuPG command line you're running? Please have a look at [ask] on what's required for asking good questions, that can actually be answered without a lot of chit-chat.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not executing the command then probably is the problem with command. First verify if path is correct or not and it is accessible from your java code or not.

Second, check permissions and try using process builder.